# Can you make SwiftUI 'hug' one control, prioritizing over another?

Tags: swiftui

Is there a way to make SwiftUI 'hug' a particular control while forcing others to 'collapse'/be trimmed?

In the example below, I have two text labels, `Headline` and `Byline` in a simple VStack with a border.  I want `Headline`--the top control--to dictate the actual width of the control while the bottom one, `Byline` will simply be trimmed.  However, I can't seem to figure out the needed magic to make this work.  In AutoLayout, this was trivial.

What I'm currently getting:

```
┌───────────────────┐
│ ~HEADLINE~        │
│ This is test text │
└───────────────────┘
```

What I want:

```
┌────────────┐
│ ~HEADLINE~ │
│ This is... │
└────────────┘
```

Below is what I've come up with so far, but it seems complete overkill having to keep essentially two copies of the `VStack`, then mirroring the properties and such on the `Text` controls to mirror the layout between the foreground and the background, but then again, it does work! Just seems unnecessary overkill.

```swift
VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
    Text("HEADLINE")
    .font(.headline)
    Text("")
}
.background {
    VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0) {
        Text("")
        .font(.headline)
        Text("Ths is a line of text I want trimmed")
    }
}
.padding(4)
.background{
    Rectangle()
    .stroke(.blue)
}
```

Comment: Try `fixedSize` modifier for the lower text, to override the default behaviour of taking up the space it needs. Also maybe`layoutPriority`.

Comment: The fixedSize modifier on the lower text seems to force it to show all of the lower text, ignoring any clipping or wrapping that would otherwise happen. I'm trying to do the exact opposite.  As for `layoutPriority`, I thought that only meant that it prioritizes one sibling over others for things that expand.  Never tried it on things that collapse.  I'll give that a spin now...

Comment: You're right, fixedSize or layoutPriority isn't going to help here.

Answer (score 1):

I would say you've got the right idea. You use the base layer to establish the footprint, then show the secondary text either as an overlay or in the background. The overlay and background automatically adopt the size of the base layer, so the secondary text will be forced to fit into this space, with truncation if necessary.

Instead of using an empty string as the placeholder on the second line, I would suggest using "." and then apply `.hidden()` to it. This way, the line height is more likely to be correct. A hidden view still plays a part in the layout, so it continues to serve the purpose of reserving vertical space. I would also apply a line limit of 1 to the visible version of the second line.

The overall construction can be done slightly more concisely too, especially since you're using the same font for all text:

```swift
VStack {
    Text("HEADLINE")
    Text(".")
        .hidden()
}
.overlay(alignment: .bottomLeading) {
    Text("This is a line of text I want trimmed")
        .lineLimit(1)
}
.font(.headline)
.padding(4)
.border(.blue)
```

[image: HEADLINE]

If there's any risk that the first line might not fit in the space available then you can force it to squeeze onto one line by setting a line limit of 1 and allowing it to be scaled:

```swift
Text("HEADLINE")
    .lineLimit(1)
    .allowsTightening(true)
    .minimumScaleFactor(0.5)
```

Alternatively, if you don't mind it wrapping then just set fixed vertical size:

```swift
Text("HEADLINE")
    .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
```

Answer (score 0):

The current answer works well and makes it clear which view is setting the size, but here's an alternative approach (if you're deployment target let's you use Grid).

```
Grid(alignment: .leading) {
  Text("HEADLINE")
  Text("This is a line of text I want trimmed")
    .gridCellUnsizedAxes(.horizontal)
    .lineLimit(1)
}
```